# Case statement based on zero records returned.

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to write a case statement that will work on zero records being returned. something like:

```
 SElect 
  Case 
      when ( 
               Select *
               from Latest_LI
                    Except distinct
               SELECT *
               FROM PRIOR_LI
             )-- This case will return zero records
       = null 
       Then 
          1
        WHEN 
          ( 
               Select *
               from Latest_LI
                    Intersect distinct
               SELECT *
               FROM PRIOR_LI
             )-- This case will return zero records
        > 0
        Then
          2
        END
```

In SQL I would assign a variable and set it to a 0 or 1 and write an IF statement that would make the correct selection.

My concern is that the case statement is only for selecting rows from the table, I want to use it for a full select based on the outcome.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little generic - so as my answer :o)

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
      SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.Latest_LI`
      EXCEPT DISTINCT
      SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.PRIOR_LI`
    )
  ) = 0 THEN 1
  WHEN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
      SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.Latest_LI`
      INTERSECT DISTINCT
      SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.PRIOR_LI`
    )
  ) > 0 THEN 2
END
```

or slightly refactored version

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CASE 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
      SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.Latest_LI`
      INTERSECT DISTINCT
      SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.PRIOR_LI`
    ))
  WHEN 0 THEN 1
  ELSE 2
END
```

Hope you got an idea

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So this works great for displaying a number, but when I try to incorporate a select statement... I get an error.  If I were to replace the  
    Then 1  with Select * from table.  I get an error.

Comment: as I mentioned  - your question was quite generic. if you have follow up questions  - I will be more than happy to answer them - please post your  new question

Comment: Sorry,  Please see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948030/using-a-case-statement-as-an-if-statement