# Using a case statement as an if statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to create an IF statement in BigQuery. I have built a concept that will work but it does not select the data from a table, I can only get it to display 1 or 0

Example:

```
SELECT --AS STRUCT 
 CASE
 WHEN (
       Select Count(1) FROM (  --  If the records are the same, then return = 0, if the records are not the same then > 1
                              Select Distinct ESCO, SOURCE, LDCTEXT, STATUS,DDR_DATE, TempF, HeatingDegreeDays, DecaTherms
                              from `gas-ddr.gas_ddr_outbound.LexingtonDDRsOutbound_onchange_Prior_Filtered` 
                                Except Distinct
                              Select Distinct ESCO, SOURCE, LDCTEXT, STATUS,DDR_DATE, TempF, HeatingDegreeDays, DecaTherms
                              from `gas-ddr.gas_ddr_outbound.LexingtonDDRsOutbound_onchange_Latest_Filtered` 
                           )
      )= 0 
  THEN 
(Select * from `gas-ddr.gas_ddr_outbound.LexingtonDDRsOutbound_onchange_Latest`)  -- This Does not 
work  Scalar subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS 
STRUCT to build STRUCT values at [16:4] END




 SELECT --AS STRUCT 
CASE
 WHEN (
       Select Count(1) FROM (  --  If the records are the same, then return = 0, if the records are not the same then > 1
                              Select Distinct ESCO, SOURCE, LDCTEXT, STATUS,DDR_DATE, TempF, HeatingDegreeDays, DecaTherms
                              from `gas-ddr.gas_ddr_outbound.LexingtonDDRsOutbound_onchange_Prior_Filtered` 
                                Except Distinct
                              Select Distinct ESCO, SOURCE, LDCTEXT, STATUS,DDR_DATE, TempF, HeatingDegreeDays, DecaTherms
                              from `gas-ddr.gas_ddr_outbound.LexingtonDDRsOutbound_onchange_Latest_Filtered` 
                           )
      )= 0 
  THEN 1 --- This does work
```

Else 
0
END

How can I Get this query to return results from an existing table?

Comment: would be great if you can explain what you want to achieve in plain english, not using the code that does not work :o) of course showing what you tried is important - but not enough to reverse-engineer your use-case :o)

Comment: Big picture: I have data that comes in to a table every day.  this data is loaded regularly via a schedule whether or not it has changed.  My end game is to display all records from this data set if any of them have changed.  If nothing has changed display zero records.
The reason we are doing this is our downstream processes will send notification if the file contains any records.
Based on this I have a bunch of views sitting on tables, that create more views and create tables this is the last stage that should pull out the data I need.

Comment: The frustrating part is this can be done in SQL easily, I am realizing BigQuery is not a replacement for SQL.

Comment: don't get frustrated  - if you are new to BigQuery - it is obvious you will have some on-boarding time to spend  - but then you will enjoy it :o) so this is your case as how I got it: `to display all records from this data set if any of them have changed. If nothing has changed display zero records` - i will get back to this when have spare time and answer it , unless someone else will jump here which is very possible :o)

Comment: Thanks! It is appreciated.  Ya I am struggling with the lack of variables, if statements, stored procedures and things like this....

Answer (score 2):

You question is still a little generic, so my answer same as well - and just mimic your use case at extend I can reverse engineer it from your comments

So, in below code - `project.dataset.yourtable` mimics your table ; whereas 
`project.dataset.yourtable_Prior_Filtered` and `project.dataset.yourtable_Latest_Filtered` mimic your respective views

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'aaa' cols, 'prior' filter UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'bbb' cols, 'latest' filter 
), `project.dataset.yourtable_Prior_Filtered` AS (
  SELECT cols FROM `project.dataset.yourtable` WHERE filter = 'prior'
), `project.dataset.yourtable_Latest_Filtered` AS (
  SELECT cols FROM `project.dataset.yourtable` WHERE filter = 'latest'
), check AS (
  SELECT COUNT(1) > 0 changed FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT cols FROM `project.dataset.yourtable_Latest_Filtered`
    EXCEPT DISTINCT
    SELECT DISTINCT cols FROM `project.dataset.yourtable_Prior_Filtered`
  )
)
SELECT t.* FROM `project.dataset.yourtable` t
CROSS JOIN check WHERE check.changed
```

the result is

```sql
Row cols    filter   
1   aaa     prior    
2   bbb     latest
```

if you changed your table to

```sql
WITH `project.dataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'aaa' cols, 'prior' filter UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'aaa' cols, 'latest' filter 
) ......
```

the result will be

```sql
Row cols    filter   
Query returned zero records.
```

I hope this gives you right direction

> Added more explanations:

I can be wrong - but per your question - it looks like you have one table `project.dataset.yourtable` and two views `project.dataset.yourtable_Prior_Filtered` and `project.dataset.yourtable_Latest_Filtered` which present state of your table prior and after some event

So, first three CTE in the answer above just mimic those table and views which you described in your question. 
They are here so you can see concept and can play with it without any extra work before adjusting this to your real use-case.

For your real use-case you should omit them and use your real table and views names and whatever columns the have.
So the query for you to play with is:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH check AS (
  SELECT COUNT(1) > 0 changed FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT cols FROM `project.dataset.yourtable_Latest_Filtered`
    EXCEPT DISTINCT
    SELECT DISTINCT cols FROM `project.dataset.yourtable_Prior_Filtered`
  )
)
SELECT t.* FROM `project.dataset.yourtable` t
CROSS JOIN check WHERE check.changed
```

> It should be a very simple IF statement in any language.
>   Unfortunately NO! it cannot be done with just simple `IF` and if you see it fit you can submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149) to BigQuery team  for whatever you think makes sense

Comment: I am even more confused than I was before. Maybe I did not explain what I am trying to do correctly... I will try to simplify it as much as I can. 

I want to write something that will either select the records from TABLE A OR ZERO RECORDS from the same table based on the results from the combination of 2 other tables. It should be a very simple IF statement in any language.  
If Count of (x) >= 0 THEN Select x From Table Else Select top 0 from Table. 
I am not sure what your code is doing, I am having a hard time following it.

Comment: added "explanation" in answer